# gdb-multiarch lx-symbols failed

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, arm64, gdb-python

I am trying to debug an aarch64 Linux kernel loaded in QEMU from x86 host. When 'lx-symbols' command executed for loading the symbols from gdb, it has shown

```
Undefined command: "lx-symbols"
```

The I have tried executing 'add-auto-load-safe-path' command as shown below

```
gdb-multiarch  /mykernelbuild/linux/arch/arm64/boot/Image

gdb) target remote localhost:9000
Remote debugging using localhost:9000
warning: No executable has been specified and target does not support
determining executable automatically.  Try using the "file" command.

add-auto-load-safe-path /mykernelbuild/linux/scripts/gdb
```

Still 'lx-symbols' is returning error. I have tried adding this to '~/.gdbint' and restarting 'gdb-multiarch' as well. I have tried adding the filename also to the path

```
add-auto-load-safe-path /mykernelbuild/linux/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py
```

still no success, any hint is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `gdb-multiarch  /mykernelbuild/linux/arch/arm64/boot/Image`

You are debugging `Image`, and not `vmlinux`. So GDB will attempt to auto-load `Image-gdb.py` (which is nowhere to be found).

I have no idea what `boot/Image` is, but you probably want to be debugging `boot/vmlinux` instead.

**Update:**

> `add-auto-load-safe-path /mykernelbuild/linux/scripts/gdb`

Now GDB is complaining about the `/mykernelbuild/linux/scripts/gdb` not being in the `auto-load-safe-path` (which it wouldn't be since you haven't added it yet).

You want something like:

```
gdb-multiarch -ex 'add-auto-load-safe-path /mykernelbuild/linux/scripts/gdb' \
  /mykernel/linux/vmlinux
```

Comment: Thank you very much. `$ gdb-multiarch  /mykernel/linux/vmlinux
...
Reading symbols from /mykernel/linux/vmlinux...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mykernel/linux/vmlinux-gdb.py", line 25, in <module>
    import linux.utils
  File "/mykernel/linux/scripts/gdb/linux/utils.py", line 131, in <module>
    atomic_long_counter_offset = atomic_long_type.get_type()['counter'].bitpos
KeyError: 'counter'`  `add-auto-load-safe-path /mykernelbuild/linux/scripts/gdb (gdb) lx-symbols` lx-symbols still returns undefined command, but I am able to see the source now. Anything wrong here?

Comment: Thank you. The error still remains, it looks like the python script has some error. My default python is 2.7.18. can it be related to that?